# vue comment not appended

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

My Vue Code is not working until I refresh the page. The reply of the comment goes to database successfully, but is not showing in browser until I refresh the page or I add a comment then refresh then add reply.

Comments.vue

My Methods

```
appendReply(comment,reply){
    _.find(this.comments, { id: comment.id }).children.push(reply)
},
```

Mounted

```
bus.$on('comment:replied', ({ comment, reply }) => {
    this.appendReply(comment, reply)
    this.scrollToComment(reply)
})
```

I'm getting this error in console

> [Vue warn]: Error in event handler for "comment:replied": "TypeError:
>   Cannot read property 'push' of undefined"

Comment: add console log to `_.find(this.comments, { id: comment.id })`

Comment: @RadonirinaMaminiaina i did this is a screen show http://prntscr.com/notdi8

Comment: @RadonirinaMaminiaina this is how it reurn whern i refresh page and try bto reply http://prntscr.com/noteyd

Comment: @RadonirinaMaminiaina and this is without refreshing http://prntscr.com/notfd4

Comment: you need to add the children property and set empty array as value I think

Comment: @RadonirinaMaminiaina  How will i fetch children property with comment children  ??

Comment: @RadonirinaMaminiaina i'm using this in my resource could it be the reason  ?             'children' => CommentResource::collection($this->whenLoaded('children')),

Answer (score 0):

Since I know where you got this code and what is the flow I will give you the solution to your issue.

Alex when he was explaining the `appendReply` method kept the `whenLoaded` in `CommentResource` on the replies(children).

To resolve this issue you need to go to your Commentresource class provided by the backend and set replies (children) property to this code :

```
'replies' => CommentResource::collection($this->replies)
```

or in your case

```
'children' => CommentResource::collection($this->children)
```